# Get conclusion condition from all value in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, logic, android-sqlite, conditional-statements

I have a database table in sqlite with two columns; named "Id" and "status"
The default status for all Id is "0"

```
Id    |    status
-----------------
A     |    0
B     |    0
C     |    0
D     |    0
```

When I starts the activity, the status change to "1"; one by one

```
Id    |    status
-----------------
A     |    1
B     |    0
C     |    0
D     |    0
```

When the status reach "1" for all Id, I want to proceed to the next activity

```
Id    |    status
-----------------
A     |    1
B     |    1
C     |    1
D     |    1
```

Here's some code

```
public String check() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] coloumns = new String[]{"idx", "status"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String result = " ";
    Cursor c = db.query("DATA", coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    int rowid = c.getColumnIndex("idx");
    int rowstat = c.getColumnIndex("status");
    c.moveToFirst();
    String midx = c.getString(rowid);
    String mstat = c.getString(rowstat);
    for (int i = 1; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

        ***i don't know how the code for logic/conditions here***

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Query for all the items where status is not equal to 1.  When the count is 0, you're done.

Comment: so I just using some buffer from that? for example when I finish one Id, the buffer is +1. And then when the buffer reach as same as the total sum of the Id, the buffer counting is finished and I can proceed to the next activity, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you used `SELECT sum(status) AS resolved_status FROM DATA`  for the query, this would return a cursor with a single row having a single column named resolved_status the value being the sum of the status column for the rows.

So when **resolved_status** is 4 then your condition is met.

As such your `check` method could be :-

```
public boolean check() {
    String column_name = "resolved_status";
    int resolved_status = 0; // default unchecked therefore false
    String[] coloumns = new String[]{"sum(status) AS " + column_name}; //<<<< CHANGED
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query("DATA", coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        resolved_status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(column_name));
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return (resolved_status == 4);
}
```

Note that the signature has been changed so that the `check` method returns a boolean so you can use `if (check()) { //do something } else { //do another thing }`